# Ruby's `Process.fork` and `Errno::EAGAIN` due to batch forking

Tags: ruby, exception, process, fork

I am trying to accomplish something using Ruby's `Process.fork`. However, after only a few seconds it'll raise the following exception: `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable - fork(2) (Errno::EAGAIN)`

From what I understand, after doing some research, is that the OS has a limit as to how many processes are allowed to run on the OS. And the above error indicates that limit was exceeded from what I read.

What I do not understand however is how this limit gets exceeded while I explicitly `Process.wait` at the end for all child processes to finish before re-looping the same code. The first 10 or-so loops it works fine, but after that the `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable - fork(2) (Errno::EAGAIN)` shows itself again.

Here's a simple example of what I'm doing:

```
loop do
  records = MyDatabase.find_batch_of_25_records_to_process_concurrently
  records.each do |record|
    Process.fork do # Spawn 25 child processes, one for each record
      record.process!
    end
  end

  Process.wait # wait until 25 Child Processes are finished/killed (, right?)
  sleep 5
end
```

So what happens is that I fetch 25 records from my database, then I want to process them concurrently. So I loop through each record, and fork a process for each of them. It'll end up having forked the main process 25 times. Then I call `Process.wait` so it doesn't re-loop until all child processes are finished. Then it'll sleep for 5 seconds and repeat the process, re-forking 25 new child processes, etc.

Does anyone have any clue why, after a couple of loops, this error ( `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable - fork(2) (Errno::EAGAIN)` ) is being raised? And hopefully, how to prevent it from happening? Looking at my ActivityMonitor, I see 25 new Ruby processes getting spawned. Then after 2 or-so seconds they all disappear again because they finished their tasks. Then 25 new processes appear in the Activity Monitor, and then disappear again. So I am assuming they are in fact being spawned and killed, but still the error is being raised.

Any feedback much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `Process.wait` is the cause of this issue. I think it might not properly register a child process as "finished" this way.

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
loop do
  pids    = Array.new # Create a local variable to hold an array of pids
  records = MyDatabase.find_batch_of_25_records_to_process_concurrently
  records.each do |record|
    pids << Process.fork do # Fork a child, and add it's returned pid to the array
      record.process!
    end
  end

  pids.each do |pid|
    Process.wait(pid) # Explicitly wait for **each** pid individually
  end
  sleep 5
end
```

This seems to work fine and it is no longer crashing with 10 seconds. I'm going to leave this running for a while and see if it ends up crashing afterall. In any case, thus far it looks like the `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable - fork(2) (Errno::EAGAIN)` error isn't based raised any longer this way.

Answer (score 1):

Is not simpler `Process.waitall` ?